# Need help and hints on an integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration

Can anyone give me a couple of hints on how should I start out with this integral, mind you I need only hints. I'll solve it myself.

$$\displaystyle{\int \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x^4 + 4x -5}}}$$

Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pedant, but are you sure it is a quartic in the sqrt?

Comment: @Kevin yea, if it were a quadratic, it would be easily solvable. But I'm sure it's $x^4$ in there

Comment: Did you try [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt(x%5E4+%2B+4x+-5))?

Comment: Solution is very complicated and contains elliptic integral of the first kind and another stuff.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk But I know the elliptic integrals...

Comment: Nevermind. I'll somehow figure it out myself.

Comment: I am therefore not so sure you will find an elementary function representation. Do post your results though!